# Why does a native query drastically speed up a named query?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, jpql

I have been experiencing some performance issues with a JPA query recently and began investigating ways to resolve it.

I have the following named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "EquipmentBooked.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM EquipmentBooked e")
```

which I then timed as following:

```
String timings += "\nEquipmentBooked";
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<EquipmentBooked> equipmentBookings = entityManager.createNamedQuery("EquipmentBooked.findAll", EquipmentBooked.class).getResultList();
timings += " - Query time [ms]: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
for(EquipmentBooked booking : equipmentBookings){
    log.info(booking.getEquipmentBookedId());
}
timings += " - Total time [ms]: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

The result was:

```
EquipmentBooked - Query time [ms]: 333405 - Total time [ms]: 333460
```

**333 seconds** for only about 2000 records!

I then decided to give a native query a try:

```
String timings += "\nEquipmentBooked (native)";
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<EquipmentBooked> nativeEquipmentBooked = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from EQUIPMENT_BOOKED", EquipmentBooked.class).getResultList();
timings += " - Query time [ms]: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
for(EquipmentBooked booking : nativeEquipmentBooked){
    log.info(booking.getEquipmentBookedId());
}
timings += " - Total time [ms]: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

This resulted in:

```
EquipmentBooked (native) - Query time [ms]: 6607 - Total time [ms]: 6767
```

**6 seconds!** Much better.

It got interesting when I ran both of these queries in the same method, the native first then the named query. The result was:

```
EquipmentBooked (native) - Query time [ms]: 6607 - Total time [ms]: 6767
EquipmentBooked - Query time [ms]: 699 - Total time [ms]: 774
```

Can anyone explain why the native query is so much faster and increases performance of the named query?

*Note: These tests were all run before any entities had been cached and the database is Oracle.*

**Update:** Removed join fetch to make sure the queries are the same.

**Update 2:** After looking at the SQL that is generated, the only difference I can see is the following:

```
SELECT EQUIPMENT_BOOKED_ID, CALENDAR_ENTRY_ID, EQUIPMENT_BOOKED_STATUS_ID, EQUIPMENT_ID, EXPERIMENT_PART_ID FROM EQUIPMENT_BOOKED
```

Vs.

```
select * from EQUIPMENT_BOOKED
```

In both cases the JPA driver goes off and fetches the (many) relationships in the same way. E.g.:

```
SELECT CALENDAR_ENTRY_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, DESCRIPTION, FROM_DATE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATE, THRU_DATE, TO_DATE FROM CALENDAR_ENTRY WHERE (CALENDAR_ENTRY_ID = ?)
```

Comment: Your native query is not the same as the NamedQuery. It's missing a join.

Comment: True. But the question still stands, why does the native query make the named query faster at getting the same data?

Comment: I've noticed that when you compare two things that don't have the same end result, you can create all sorts of crazy looking tests and comparisons. If you don't do proper tests, don't expect proper answers.

Comment: The join was a late addition, prior to it the time was still roughly the same. I can actually remove it now. I'll update the question when I've re-run the test.

Comment: @Kayaman I've updated the question.

Comment: My guess is the difference in timings between the first and second runs is due to the data being cached on the db side of things, meaning the db doesn't need to go back to the disk to fetch the data. It will be interesting to see what your subsequent timings are.

Comment: @Boneist That was my guess too, but I'm more interested in why the native query run alone vs the named run alone is so much faster with no caching between them being called (application redeployed)

Comment: What happens if you run the named query twice in a row? Are the timings consistent?

Comment: The second call is much lower due to using the cache.

Comment: Does it match the timings that you saw when calling the native then the named queries? I would expect the second run, whether it was native or named to be faster, due to the data being cached on the db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86798/discussion-between-averagemarcus-and-boneist).

Comment: I can't access chat, sadly.

Comment: Ah! OK. Not really. The native query is pretty much always 6 seconds (regardless of cache). The named query takes ages without the cache, then its less then a second.

Comment: Do you restart the Oracle as well before you run the tests?

Comment: No, I don't have control over the database.